# Reverse VPN to access remote network

Tags: vpn, remote-access, reverse-tunnel

**Setup:**

- VPN Server site (L2TP UniFi-Security-Gateway), exposed to the internet (secured)
- VPN Client site (Ubuntu server connecting to VPN server)
- Reverse VPN between the sites, client can press "connect" for remote service.

This is because we do not want to rely on our clients to open firewall ports and aside of that we do not always have control over the client's router.

[image: vpn connection diagram]

---

**Question:**

How can I connect the remote service PC to the client network (as if it was in the client network).

I simply want to be able to do a network scan from the remote service PC, to see if all devices are online and be able to access the webpages of the clients.

**The problem/questions:**

Currently the "Server (VPN client)" connects to my Unifi Security Gateway. Which makes the server able to see my local network/devices. But I am not able to see the remote network/devices.

I'm thinking that my "Server (VPN client)" would need to have a route from the VPN to the Client router.

But I'm not all too certain about how the "Remote service PC" can choose to connect the client network (possibly put the "Server (VPN Client)"'s IP as a router/gateway.

---

Please let me know if the above statements are correct or if this is not the 'usual' way to do this.

Comment: Are there valid routes between your "remote service PC" network and the client router? I notice you have a 192.168.1.x subnet trying to work with a 192.168.55.x subnet. A 255.255.255.0 subnet will allow you to have 254 usable hosts so a 192.168.1.x subnet (say, a typical home router, will be 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.254) will need a router to be able to communicate with the 192.168.55.x subnet.

Comment: Hmm, I'm just thinking, the whole routing is the wrong way around. But that's because I connect from the remote to local. So I'm not actually sure if this is the proper way to deal with it